# How can be found slow connection reason to database on other computer in local network?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, network-share

**How can be found slow connection reason to database on other computer in local network?**

We have on our computers + Apache + MySql +Ubuntu.
My computer connected to other local network computer.
My computer use Database from other computer.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

First, use [iperf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf/) to test network. If no problems, then the case in database.

jperf screen in Ubuntu:
[image]

Comment: does iperf has ui?

Comment: Yes, http://code.google.com/p/xjperf/

Comment: I install program on ubuntu, but I dont see any ui

Comment: check my screanshot

Comment: iperf always be taking my bucket. loldiagnostics.

Comment: @John you can use iperf from terminal without gui

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the slow connection reason is due to a resolution name problem.

Try to connect using only ip address.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by running a simple ping and then a  trace route between the machines (may be tracepath in ubuntu) and check what your latency is ... if that looks good try running the same query on the database machine and check how long it takes.  If everything looks good there its probably worth using wireshark to see what is really going on network wise